# How to rotate an object using "Pivot center for rotation : 3D Cursor" with python script in Blender

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to rotate a selected part of a cube on Z axes 30 degrees by using 3D Cursor .
I select the folowing part :
[StartImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00u6q.png)

I should get something like this after rotation  :
[CorrectImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co54g.png)

And this my script python. Everything is fine but he makes the roatation incorrectly by using Bounding Box Center mod while I'm telling to him make it with the Cursor Pivot Center.

With this script I'm getting :
[BadResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weQ5e.png)

```py
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 1, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')


#for i in range(len(obj.data.polygons) ):
obj.data.polygons[5].select = True
#bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location= (2.073, 0.0, 0.0)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR' 
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-0.523599, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='VIEW', orient_matrix=((-1, -0, 0), (-0, 1.34359e-07, 1), (-0, 1, 1.34359e-07)), orient_matrix_type='VIEW',
 mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

Can you help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Does this help : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/rotate-object-around-cursor-with-python

Comment: thnaky you this page helped me